# Как перехватить WinAPI функцию CreateProcess в C++/C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows, c++

Моя программа должна блокировать запуск определенных расширений(например, запретить запуск exe-файлов) в определенных каталогов(например, "C:Temp"). Вопрос: как перехватить WinAPI-функцию CreateProcess, и если не удовлетворяет нашему условию, то завершать CreateProcess?

Comment: Хотелось бы найти русскоязычную статью, но все равно спасибо! Но если есть у кого какие-нибудь исходники буду очень благодарен, если поделитесь такой ценной информацией!

Answer (score 4):

эту задачу можно решить на уровне [политик](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx)

а если нужно именно перехватывать создание процесса, то можно установить глобальный хук, можете почитать [тут](http://forum.sysinternals.com/createprocess-api-hook_topic13138.html)